# How to use webcam to scan barcode?

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

I need to make an android app in which, I need to scan the barcode. But the issue is that I do not have an android phone and plan to use the emulator. I was wondering if I could use my webcam to scan the barcode and then feed it to my program to make this work. Are there any available open source libraries which allow me to do so? To be able to read qr code through the same would be a bonus.

Comment: Library:[ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/). The webcam part depends on the emulator really. Bluestacks could probably do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sould look into [zXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) a great library for reading barcodes and qrcodes. It uses BarcodeScanner to read the Barcode and pass the readed info in an intent back to your app. Look at [ScanningViaIntent](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent) for that.

About the Camera, my own experience with the ADV was awful, is always better a device. If you have you use the ADV camera it seems that ICS ADV supports the use of the pc web camera as the device camera.

Answer (score 1):

Android emulator supports using your webcam, see details [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html).